# Asymptotic behavior of a particular function.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $K\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ be a compact set. What does the following mean

> $$\log |x-y|=\log |x|+ O(1)\quad\text{when}\; |x|\to\infty\quad\text{and}\quad y\in K$$

**My attempt.**
We observe that $$\log |x-y|=\log\left(\frac{|x-y|}{|x|}\right)+\log |x|.$$ Now, I prove that $$\left |\log\left( \frac{|x-y|}{|x|}\right)\right | \le  \frac{C}{|x|} $$
Results that
$$
\begin{align}
\left | \log \frac{|x-y|}{|x|}\right |\le \frac{|x-y|}{|x|}-1\le \frac{|y|}{|x|}\color{RED}{\le}\frac{C}{|x|}
\end{align}
$$
since $y\in K$ I used the fact that $|y|\le C$ where $C>0$ is some constant. It's correct?

Thanks!

Comment: It means that the function
$$f(x,y):=\log |x-y|-\log |x|$$
(where $|~|$ denotes some norm on $\Bbb R^2$) satisfies:
$$\exists M,N\quad\forall y\in K\quad\forall x\text{ such that }|x|\ge N\quad|f(x,y)|\le M.$$

Comment: The answer of @AnneBauval is correct. In words, your statement is the assertion that $\log|x-y|-\log|x|$ is bounded for $x$ with large enough magnitude $|x|$.

Comment: Your $f(x,y)\le0$ "for $|x|\to\infty$" (meaning for $|x|$ large enough?) is useless and generally false. A better tool is triangular inequality $|x|-|y|\le|x-y|\le|x|+|y|$, and the fact that $K$ is bounded.

Comment: I think the following inequality may be relevant:$$1-\frac1x\le\ln x\le x-1$$for $x\ge0$.